# Bad alignment of Author and Title in Beamer class (Warsaw theme)

Tags: beamer, header-footer, vertical-alignment

I just uninstalled TeX Live 2016 and installed TeX Live 2017 and I noticed that the vertical alignment of author and title in any `beamer` presentation with Warsaw theme has been disrupted. In this example the author is `JESTIN` and the title is `Beamer Intro`. How can I vertical center them?

Moreover, I just found the same bug in the `beamer` guide obtained writing `texdoc beamer` in the command prompt, in the part of a `warsaw` presentation.

[image: Here the bad vertical alignment of JESTIN and Beamer Intro]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{warsaw}

\title[Beamer Intro]{Beamer - Introduction to \LaTeX{} presentation making}
\author[JESTIN]{Jestin Joy}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange!

Comment: I am wondering if this is a feature rather than a bug. `author` seems centered horizontally at the center of the shadow of the title box (rather than the actual title box). Arguably, it hence gives the impression of 3D.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question since it is a bug that will be fixed with a future update of the package.

Comment: @Werner I don't think it should be closed, see https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6988/36296

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This bug has already been fixed in version 3.48, see https://github.com/josephwright/beamer/commit/f09629cdc88bcceb4e0446f16966489733bf6914

As a temporary workaround until 3.48 reaches ctan, place https://raw.githubusercontent.com/josephwright/beamer/master/base/beamerbasecolor.sty in the same folder as your `.tex` document.

[image]