# Beamer File does not render correctly on different machine

Tags: beamer, header-footer, vertical-alignment

Here's the code

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=43,10pt]{beamer} % 4:3 = 43, 16:9 = 169
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % Deutsch
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % Deutsch
\usepackage{mytemplate} % Anpassungen
\usepackage{graphicx} % Grafiken
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{calc} % Optionen für plots und für template!
\listfiles
% ------------------------------------------------------------- %
% T I T L E
% ------------------------------------------------------------- % 
\author{John Doe}
\date{\today}
% ------------------------------------------------------------- %
% C O M M A N D S 
% ------------------------------------------------------------- % 
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty % Keine Navbar
\setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt plus 3pt minus 2pt} 
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos}
\newcommand\FrameText[1]{%
  \begin{textblock*}{\paperwidth}(0pt,\textheight)
    \raggedright #1\hspace{.5em}
  \end{textblock*}}
% ------------------------------------------------------------- %
% B E G I N  D O C U M E N T 
% ------------------------------------------------------------- %
\begin{document}
% ------------------------------------------------------------- %
% I N H A L T
% ------------------------------------------------------------- % 
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{\textbf{Inhalt}}
Hello World!
\end{frame} 
\end{document}
```

Contents of mytemplate

```
% ------------------------------------------------------------- %
% F A R B E N
% ------------------------------------------------------------- %  
\definecolor{footcol}{RGB}{50,50,50}
\definecolor{color1}{RGB}{70,70,70}
% ------------------------------------------------------------- %
% F O O T L I N E 
% ------------------------------------------------------------- %   
\setbeamercolor{customfootline}{fg=footcol}
\setbeamerfont{customfootline}{series=\mdseries}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}
{
  \leavevmode%
    \centering
    \rule{0.95\paperwidth}{0.5pt}
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.33\paperwidth,ht=3.25ex,dp=3ex,left]{customfootline}%
    \usebeamerfont{customfootline}\hspace*{2em}\insertdate
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.33\paperwidth,ht=3.25ex,dp=3ex,center]{customfootline}%
    \usebeamerfont{customfootline}\insertauthor
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.33\paperwidth,ht=3.25ex,dp=3ex,right]{customfootline}%
    \usebeamerfont{customfootline}
    Folie \insertframenumber{}\hspace*{2em}
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
% ------------------------------------------------------------- %
% H E A D L I N E 
% ------------------------------------------------------------- %  
\setbeamercolor{customheadline}{fg=footcol}
\setbeamerfont{customheadline}{series=\mdseries}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=6.5ex,dp=1ex,left]{customheadline}%
    \usebeamerfont{customheadline}\begin{tabular}{ll}
         \parbox[c]{4ex}{\includegraphics[height=5ex]{src/dummy.png}}&\raisebox{-0.3ex}{\parbox[c]{\widthof{Bla bla bla bla bla}}{Bla bla bla bla bla}} 
        \end{tabular}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \hfill
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=6.5ex,dp=1ex,right]{customheadline}%
    \usebeamerfont{customheadline}
\begin{tabular}{ll}
        \parbox[c]{6ex}{\includegraphics[height=5ex]{src/dummy.png}} & \raisebox{-0.6ex}{\parbox[c]{\widthof{Bla bla bla bla bla}}{Bla bla bla bla bla\\}}
        \end{tabular}%
         \end{beamercolorbox}%
        }%
  \vskip0pt%    
\begin{center}
    \rule{0.95\paperwidth}{0.5pt}
\end{center}
}
```

And here the dummy image

[image]

Which yields

[image]

on machine 1 with package versions

```
 *File List*
  beamer.cls    2015/01/05 3.36 A class for typesetting presentations (rcs-revision 8a39122e1f63)
beamerbasercs.sty    2015/03/08 (rcs-revision 368aa9ba9d38)
beamerbasemodes.sty    2013/09/03 (rcs-revision 768f2d98ca64)
beamerbasedecode.sty    2010/05/01 (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
   ifpdf.sty    2016/05/14 v3.1 Provides the ifpdf switch
beamerbaseoptions.sty    2013/03/10 (rcs-revision 47431932db0d)
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
geometry.cfg
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2016/07/10 v1.0t Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
   xetex.def    2016/07/11 v4.10 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (L3/RRM/JK)
  pgfsys.sty    2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
  pgfrcs.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
 pgfcore.code.tex
 xxcolor.sty    2003/10/24 ver 0.1
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
hyperref.sty    2016/06/24 v6.83q Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2016/05/21 v0.22 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2016/05/16 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
refcount.sty    2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2016/06/24 v6.83q Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  hxetex.def    2016/06/24 v6.83q Hyperref driver for XeTeX
   puenc.def    2016/06/24 v6.83q Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
stringenc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.11 Convert strings between diff. encodings (HO)
rerunfilecheck.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
se-ascii-print.def    2016/05/16 v1.11 stringenc: Printable ASCII characters
beamerbaserequires.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbasecompatibility.sty    2012/05/01  (rcs-revision 67c48b3b652d)
beamerbasefont.sty    2015/01/05  (rcs-revision b4b4bee242e2)
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
sansmathaccent.sty    2013/03/28
filehook.sty    2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
beamerbasetranslator.sty    2010/06/11  (rcs-revision 85fd1cc7fc42)
translator.sty    2010/06/12 ver 1.10
translator-language-mappings.tex
beamerbasemisc.sty    2013/09/03  (rcs-revision a55719c41d85)
beamerbasetwoscreens.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaseoverlay.sty    2013/12/25  (rcs-revision f6bd5e3805da)
beamerbasetitle.sty    2010/09/21  (rcs-revision f0446ed0b6ae)
beamerbasesection.sty    2013/06/07  (rcs-revision 60b9fe0f342f)
beamerbaseframe.sty    2014/02/20  (rcs-revision 4b8ceeeff434)
beamerbaseverbatim.sty    2015/01/05  (rcs-revision 431510bb5890)
beamerbaseframesize.sty    2011/09/12  (rcs-revision 70f9d8411e54)
beamerbaseframecomponents.sty    2013/10/18  (rcs-revision 5cf6c5555a45)
beamerbasecolor.sty    2015/02/21  (rcs-revision d944b04ee2d5)
beamerbasenotes.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamerbasetoc.sty    2015/03/08  (rcs-revision 7270298bbaae)
beamerbasetemplates.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty    2014/06/30  (rcs-revision 580088513a67)
beamerbaseboxes.sty    2012/05/13  (rcs-revision 56972908a390)
beamerbaselocalstructure.sty    2014/09/10  (rcs-revision 393f6dcff371)
enumerate.sty    2015/07/23 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
beamerbasenavigation.sty    2015/02/27  (rcs-revision 923f4bf87efa)
beamerbasetheorems.sty    2010/06/06  (rcs-revision 7e7cc5e53e9d)
 amsmath.sty    2016/06/28 v2.15d AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
  amsthm.sty    2015/03/04 v2.20.2
beamerbasethemes.sty    2010/05/01  (rcs-revision efa082c6111d)
beamerthemedefault.sty    2010/06/17  (rcs-revision d02a7cf4d8ae)
beamerfontthemedefault.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamercolorthemedefault.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
beamerinnerthemedefault.sty    2014/06/30  (rcs-revision 580088513a67)
beamerouterthemedefault.sty    2012/12/19  (rcs-revision 1686da3db3c9)
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2016/06/19 v1.99m Standard LaTeX file
   babel.sty    2016/04/23 3.9r The Babel package
 bblopts.cfg    2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of babel
 ngerman.ldf    2016/11/02 v2.9 German support for babel (new orthography)
mytemplate.sty    
setspace.sty    2011/12/19 v6.7a set line spacing
    calc.sty    2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
 textpos.sty    2016/06/07 v1.8
 nameref.sty    2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
MWEBeamer.out
MWEBeamer.out
translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-bibliography-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-environment-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-months-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-numbers-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-theorem-dictionary-English.dict    
    umsa.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
    umsb.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
ot1mathkerncmss.fd    2013/03/27 Fontinst v1.933 font definitions for OT1/mathkerncmss.
src/dummy.png
src/dummy.png
src/dummy.png
src/dummy.png
 ***********
```

And on machine 2 it yields

[image]

with

```
 *File List*
  beamer.cls    2017/12/16 v3.47 A class for typesetting presentations
beamerbasemodes.sty    
etoolbox.sty    2017/11/22 v2.5 e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
beamerbasedecode.sty    
   ifpdf.sty    2017/03/15 v3.2 Provides the ifpdf switch
beamerbaseoptions.sty    
  keyval.sty    2014/10/28 v1.15 key=value parser (DPC)
geometry.sty    2010/09/12 v5.6 Page Geometry
  ifvtex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Detect VTeX and its facilities (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
geometry.cfg
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
 pgfcore.sty    2010/04/11 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.7)
graphicx.sty    2017/06/01 v1.1a Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2017/06/25 v1.2c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
   xetex.def    2017/06/24 v5.0h Graphics/color driver for xetex
  pgfsys.sty    2014/07/09 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.48)
  pgfrcs.sty    2015/08/07 v3.0.1a (rcs-revision 1.31)
everyshi.sty    2001/05/15 v3.00 EveryShipout Package (MS)
  pgfrcs.code.tex
  pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2013/09/09  (rcs-revision 1.9)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2006/10/16  (rcs-revision 1.4)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
 pgfcore.code.tex
 xxcolor.sty    2003/10/24 ver 0.1
atbegshi.sty    2016/06/09 v1.18 At begin shipout hook (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.23 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
hyperref.sty    2017/03/14 v6.85a Hypertext links for LaTeX
hobsub-hyperref.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset hyperref (HO)
hobsub-generic.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Bundle oberdiek, subset generic (HO)
  hobsub.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Construct package bundles (HO)
ifluatex.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
 intcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Expandable calculations with integers (HO)
etexcmds.sty    2016/05/16 v1.6 Avoid name clashes with e-TeX commands (HO)
kvsetkeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.17 Key value parser (HO)
kvdefinekeys.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Define keys (HO)
pdftexcmds.sty    2017/03/19 v0.25 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
pdfescape.sty    2016/05/16 v1.14 Implements pdfTeX's escape features (HO)
bigintcalc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Expandable calculations on big integers (HO)
  bitset.sty    2016/05/16 v1.2 Handle bit-vector datatype (HO)
uniquecounter.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Provide unlimited unique counter (HO)
letltxmacro.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Let assignment for LaTeX macros (HO)
 hopatch.sty    2016/05/16 v1.3 Wrapper for package hooks (HO)
xcolor-patch.sty    2016/05/16 xcolor patch
atveryend.sty    2016/05/16 v1.9 Hooks at the very end of document (HO)
refcount.sty    2016/05/16 v3.5 Data extraction from label references (HO)
 hycolor.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Color options for hyperref/bookmark (HO)
 auxhook.sty    2016/05/16 v1.4 Hooks for auxiliary files (HO)
kvoptions.sty    2016/05/16 v3.12 Key value format for package options (HO)
  pd1enc.def    2017/03/14 v6.85a Hyperref: PDFDocEncoding definition (HO)
hyperref.cfg    2002/06/06 v1.2 hyperref configuration of TeXLive
     url.sty    2013/09/16  ver 3.4  Verb mode for urls, etc.
  hxetex.def    2017/03/14 v6.85a Hyperref driver for XeTeX
   puenc.def    2017/03/14 v6.85a Hyperref: PDF Unicode definition (HO)
stringenc.sty    2016/05/16 v1.11 Convert strings between diff. encodings (HO)
rerunfilecheck.sty    2016/05/16 v1.8 Rerun checks for auxiliary files (HO)
se-ascii-print.def    2016/05/16 v1.11 stringenc: Printable ASCII characters
beamerbaserequires.sty    
beamerbasecompatibility.sty    
beamerbasefont.sty    
 amssymb.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS font symbols
amsfonts.sty    2013/01/14 v3.01 Basic AMSFonts support
sansmathaccent.sty    2013/03/28
filehook.sty    2011/10/12 v0.5d Hooks for input files
beamerbasetranslator.sty    
translator.sty    2017/11/30 v1.11
beamerbasemisc.sty    
beamerbasetwoscreens.sty    
beamerbaseoverlay.sty    
beamerbasetitle.sty    
beamerbasesection.sty    
beamerbaseframe.sty    
beamerbaseverbatim.sty    
beamerbaseframesize.sty    
beamerbaseframecomponents.sty    
beamerbasecolor.sty    
beamerbasenotes.sty    
beamerbasetoc.sty    
beamerbasetemplates.sty    
beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty    
beamerbaseboxes.sty    
beamerbaselocalstructure.sty    
enumerate.sty    2015/07/23 v3.00 enumerate extensions (DPC)
beamerbasenavigation.sty    
beamerbasetheorems.sty    
 amsmath.sty    2017/09/02 v2.17a AMS math features
 amstext.sty    2000/06/29 v2.01 AMS text
  amsgen.sty    1999/11/30 v2.0 generic functions
  amsbsy.sty    1999/11/29 v1.2d Bold Symbols
  amsopn.sty    2016/03/08 v2.02 operator names
  amsthm.sty    2017/10/31 v2.20.4
beamerbasethemes.sty    
beamerthemedefault.sty    
beamerfontthemedefault.sty    
beamercolorthemedefault.sty    
beamerinnerthemedefault.sty    
beamerouterthemedefault.sty    
 fontenc.sty
   t1enc.def    2017/04/05 v2.0i Standard LaTeX file
  t1lmss.fd    2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
   babel.sty    2017/11/03 3.15 The Babel package
 bblopts.cfg    2005/09/08 v0.1 add Arabic and Farsi to "declared" options of babel
 ngerman.ldf    2016/11/02 v2.9 German support for babel (new orthography)
mytemplate.sty    
setspace.sty    2011/12/19 v6.7a set line spacing
    calc.sty    2014/10/28 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
 textpos.sty    2016/06/07 v1.8
 nameref.sty    2016/05/21 v2.44 Cross-referencing by name of section
gettitlestring.sty    2016/05/16 v1.5 Cleanup title references (HO)
MWEBeamer.out
MWEBeamer.out
translator-basic-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-bibliography-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-environment-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-months-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-numbers-dictionary-English.dict    
translator-theorem-dictionary-English.dict    
    umsa.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols A
    umsb.fd    2013/01/14 v3.01 AMS symbols B
src/dummy.png
src/dummy.png
src/dummy.png
src/dummy.png
 ***********
```

As you can see the position of the headerline and footline are not set correctly. TeX renders with 0 errors. I suspect that there has to be a change in one of the packages used that makes some of my code useless. I use XeLaTeX -> PDF to render on both machines as I'm using custom fonts in my project.

Comment: Can you try this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/407404/36296 ?

Comment: This fixed my problem. Do you want to close this question as a duplicate or do you want to post an answer to accept?

Comment: Good to hear the problem is solved! I closed it as duplicate.